# Tablesorter filter-onlyAvail

Tags: tablesorter

I use tablesorter (mottie's fork v2.23.0) by the gem jquery-tablesorter-rails

I have a table where I use the classes filter-select filter-onlyAvail to get a dropdown of only available options in the column.

Recently I added jeditable to the column which adds a script tag to the cells (and maybe also embed the value in a span) like this:

```
<td>                  
  <span class="editable" data-id="15" data-name="user[route]" title="Click to edit..">1</span>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    ...script for jeditable....
  </script>
</td>
```

The result is that the select filter dropdown shows all variants of values including the script contents.

I tried using filter_selectSource with the filter-match class added, but the contents of the filter is so common (like 1,2 99 etc) I get lots of false hits in the script.

Any pointers on how to ditch the contents of the script tags both in select population and in search results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using data-text="value" on the element I want to use for filter and sorting.

In my case the  tag.

This does not, however, update tablesorter's filter values or search content for an updated cell.

Comment: After updating the cell - I assume you're using the [`updateCell` method](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#updatecell)? - use `$('table').trigger('search', false)` to update the search.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`filter_selectSource` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-selectsource) to populate the filter dropdown.

Set it as an array

```
filter_selectSource : {
  0 : [ "abc", "def", "ghi", "xyz" ]
}
```

or a function:

```
filter_selectSource : function(table, column, onlyAvail){
  // get an array of all table cell contents for a table column
  var array = $.tablesorter.filter.getOptions(table, column, onlyAvail);
  // manipulate the array as desired, then return it

  return array;
}
```

Also, since it is not ideal to have inline scripts in table rows which are dynamically sorted, please check out the [`editable` widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-editable.html) which uses HTML5 contenteditable to allow user interaction.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Mottie. The filter_selectSource function unfortunately fails to filter the contents correctly. I ended up using data-text on the td tag, which works until I actually update the value in-line. Next is then to write a callback in jeditable. I'll look into using the editable widget instead.